# MVC Webframeworks

Tags: java, python, ruby-on-rails, django, model-view-controller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing a Java Web Framework now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084169/choosing-a-java-web-framework-now)

I know that Ruby-on-Rails and Django are 2 MVC oriented webframeworks, in Ruby and Python respectively. Are there any other MVC frameworks ? Any MVC frameworks that use Java ?

Comment: There are probably hundreds of MVC webframeworks frameworks that use java, just google around a bit ...

Comment: @KillianDS : I have done that - but as web-frameworks is not my strong point - I posted it here.

Comment: Maybe, but it looks like you didn't try on SO:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mvc+framework. There are dozen of similar questions, I will pick one and vote to close.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent : Yes, this is a duplication - kindly delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Something closer to rails in Java (well, not really Java) would be [Grails](http://www.grails.org/).

Of course you'd need [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) to use that, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

[CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) is a PHP MVC framework that's fairly simple to use.

Comment: why got this downvoted, there are 2 questions in the original post, one general about mvc frameworks, one specfici about java, so this answer is not incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

[**Spring MVC**](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) and [**Struts**](http://struts.apache.org/) are two popular MVC web frameworks for **Java**.